# I want to set rank to array value?

Tags: javascript

I tried to create new array object from array , set rank according to its value . If value is the same, set the same rank and if next value is different set rank by skipping same rank length .

Expected result is

> [
>     {
>       "rank": 1,
>       "data": 45
>     },
>     {
>       "rank": 2,
>       "data": 33
>     },
>     {
>       "rank": 3,
>       "data": 8
>     },
>     {
>       "rank": 4,
>       "data": 5
>     },
>     {
>       "rank": 4,
>       "data": 5
>     },
>     {
>       "rank": 6,
>       "data": 2
>     }
>   ]

```js
var data = [8,5,2,33,5,45];

var rankList = [];

var uniqueList = [];

var rank = 0;
var sameRank = 0;

data.sort(function(a,b) { return b - a; });

for(var i in data) {
   if(uniqueList.includes(data[i])) {
      rank++;
      rankList.push({rank: sameRank, data: data[i]});
      continue;
   }
   rank++;
   sameRank++;
   rankList.push({rank: rank, data: data[i]});
}


console.log(rankList);
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Could you attempt to re-state your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've sorted the array, create another array of objects with `.map`, keeping track of the last `rank` and `data` used. If the new data is the same, use the same rank (the one taken from a prior iteration) - otherwise, use the current iteration index plus 1:

```js
const data = [8, 5, 2, 33, 5, 45];
data.sort((a, b) => b - a);

let lastRank = 0;
let lastData;
const output = data.map((data, i) => {
  const objToReturn = { data };
  objToReturn.rank = data === lastData ? lastRank : i + 1;
  lastData = data;
  lastRank = objToReturn.rank;
  return objToReturn;
});
console.log(output);
```